# how to call a service in vanilla js in a asp.net model

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call a service in js in a asp.net model. 
can you please help me find the right structure,
here is my general code.

```
GetSomething: function () {
            var something;
           System.SomeService.GetSomething(new Report.DocumentsRequest(), null, function (response) {
               return something = Report.GetResponse(response);???
           });
           return something = Report.GetResponse(response);???
            //
        },
```

tank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell out of context, but it looks as though you're attempting to mix C# code with JavaScript code. If that's the case, you cannot do that. Instead, you need to provide an endpoint (controller action) that accesses your service and returns the results as something like JSON. Then, you need to utilize AJAX (the `XMLHttpRequest` object) in your JavaScript to make a request to that endpoint.